# ошибка в php коде

Tags: php, html

```
<form action='update_user' method='post'>
    <input class='auth_input' name='login' type='text'>
    <input class='auth_button' type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>


<?
$f_log = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE activation = '1'");
$f_log_r = mysqli_fetch_array($f_log);

$login = $_POST['login'];
$login = stripslashes($login); $login = htmlspecialchars($login); $login = trim($login);
if (isset($_POST['login'])){

    if (empty($login)) { $empty_data = 1;}

    else{

        if ($f_log_r['login'] == $login) {$reg_login = 1;}

        else{

            if (strlen($login) < 3 or strlen($login) > 16) {$too_long = 1;}

            else{

                $result3 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE users SET login='$login' WHERE login='$old_login'");
                if ($result3=='TRUE') { //ошибка как минимум здесь, 'TRUE' != 1 и != true, это условие никогда не выполнится
                    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE messages SET author='$login' WHERE author='$old_login'");
                    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;//Обновляем логин в сессии
                    if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) {
                        setcookie("login", $login, time()+9999999);//Обновляем логин в куках
                    }

                    $data = 1;}//отправляем пользователя назад

            }
        }
    }
}
```

в чем ошибка (ошибки)

Comment: Это надо у вас спрашивать в чём ошибка? что в логах?

Comment: @Naumov Простите что за логи?

Comment: Логи сервера куда ошибки пишуться. И да https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/ru/coding-standard.coding-style.html почитайте на досуге.

Comment: @Naumov в логах ничего

Comment: что тогда не работает?

Comment: `$result3=='TRUE'` не нужен. достаточно `if($result3)`

Comment: это что за лесинка из if else )))

Answer (score 2):

отредактировал вопрос и -

```
$result3 = mysqli_query(/*...*/)
if ($result3=='TRUE') { //ошибка как минимум здесь, 
// 'TRUE' != 1 и 'TRUE' != true, это условие никогда не выполнится.
```

для сравнения:

```
<?php
var_dump( 1=='TRUE'); //false
var_dump( 1==true); //true
```

кроме того

закрывающий тег `?>` не нужен и [признан](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4499749/5006740) вредным

Comment: Кстати, 'TRUE'  == true, но 'true' !== true, а еще 'false' == true, строка же :)